# Performance considration between Cursor with 30000 record or create 30000 update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, cursor

Which is better?

1)A cursor that loop 30000 record and perform update one by one

2)Create a script that has 30000 update command

thanks

Comment: 3) A script that performs all of the updates on the entire set, rather than 30000 updates (whether scripted or via cursor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both should take about the same time, mainly subject to how the CURSOR is declared.

Reason? You have 30,000 individual updates which is usually the main factor

Note that 30,000 individual UPDATES in one batch will probably fail because of batch size and compile time anyway...

SQL is a set based language and you can most likely do a single UPDATE to update all rows in one go. If you can't, it is because of 2 reasons

1. You need "per row" logic: this can usually be achieved by CASE expressions, UDFs etc
2. You don't understand sets and SQL

With more information (the SQL and logic) we could help you more...

Answer (score 0):

There is a very easy way to tell: Do it and measure the time.

Other than that, having 30000 lines does not make a lot of sense when you can have just 10.

Making updates this way for reasons other than data migration or maintenance doesn't sound like wise either, and in those cases performance is not an issue - but maintenance and legibility always is.

Answer (score 0):

You know, that depends on context.

It helps, though, to learn. SQL for example. You are on a low level not to see the real optimizations possible here. SQL is a lot more than just Update, Insert and simple Select statements.

> 1)A cursor that loop 30000 record and perform update one by one

Linear step by step processing. No way to paralellize as SQL itself has no threading mechanisms available to the user; Optimizations are one by one - i.e. the query optimizer looks at items one statement at a time.

> 2)Create a script that has 30000 update command

Assuming the script is external, it could split the work and run it concurrent on multiple connections, i.e. run more than one parallel.

But there is more:

- Make a script that calculates the new values.
- Bulk import them into a temporary table using the buld copy API
- Issue ONE update statment that takes the updated values from the temporary table to the final one.

Maybe have a script that issues a merge statement for multi update? There are tons of variations there if you know the SQL api more than "update, open cursor, simple select".

I do that - though a lot more data (batches of 50.000, sometimes 4-6 at the same time). The problem being that sql bulk copy has some overhead. But I manage 75.000 inserts per second that way.

A lot depends on the business questions and the complexity of the logic - if it is simple updates then the question is: Calculated or externally driven?  Multiple values by 2 = calculated, updating addresses = data driven (i.e. you need the new data from somewhere).

Comment: @gbn Some simple math. THis is a democracy. 50% of the people have below average intelligence. Anyone feeling insulted - he belongs to them because THIS IS THE DEFINITION OF AVERAGE in a gaussian distribution. But that means any smart anser already has 50% of the people with problems understanding it.